# How does a website know my laptop is connected to an external monitor?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video-streaming, hardware, hdcp

I was on a video streaming website, and it notified me that I am not allowed to view the video because it detects that my browser is connected to an external monitor. 
How does the browser detect this?

Comment: What is the site?

Comment: www.kanopy.com/

Comment: I found that safari doesn't trigger this warning vs Chrome

Answer (score 2):

Its part of the DRM system. Your browser ships with a Content decryption module (CDM) to securely play back DRM content.